# Wikipedia API JSONP request blocked mime type mismatch

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, mime-types

I am trying to get random pages from the Wikipedia API using JSONP. In chrome and IE11 it gives me  URL name "was blocked due to mime type mismatch".

Here is my JSONP request.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=5",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    format: "json",
  
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste the url in a browser and check the HTML response you will find the instructions in there. Basically you have to add format=json as a query string parameter.

Try the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnlimit=5&format=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",

    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the callback parameter in the url instead: (this have worked for me before)

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=YOURACTION&OTHERPARAMS&callback=wikiCallback",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success: function(data){doSmth()}
})
```